# Allow edu domain emails in form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I tried various solutions but it didn't work. Not that good with JavaScript especially with RegEx.
Found this solution online, but couldn't modify it.

Basically I need to allow EDU domain in email field. I think it would be @ohio.edu or @ohio.edu.com or something like that. How can I say that if there isn't phrase "edu" after @, then don't allow the registration?

```js
$(".single-memberpressproduct.postid-1945 .mepr-submit").click(function() {
  validateEmail(jQuery("input#user_email1").val());
  return false;
});

function validateEmail(email) {
  var emailRegx = /b(?:(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-z0-9_.-]+(?<![_.-]))@(?:(?!-)(?!.*--)[a-z0-9-]+(?<!-).)*.edub/i;
  if (emailRegx.test(email)) {
    if (email.indexOf('@edu.com', email.length - '@edu.com'.length) !== -1) {
      alert('Submission was successful.');
    } else {
      alert('Not a valid e-mail address @.');
    }
  } else {
    alert('Not a valid e-mail address.');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="single-memberpressproduct postid-1945">
  <input type="text" id="user_email1" value="" />
  <input type="submit"  class="mepr-submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please correct any assumptions I had about you HTML. Also I STRONGLY recommend you to use the submit event and use event.reventDefault() instead of click of a submit button

Comment: What is `*.edub` supposed to be?

Comment: @mplungjan not sure, I copied the solution. Where did you make a snippet?

Comment: I added a snippet of your code in your question. Reload the page. You will not match .edu if you end your regex on `edub`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using different approach.

```
<script>
jQuery('.single-memberpressproduct.postid-1945 .mepr-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
var youtubeRegex = /edu/i;
jQuery('input#user_email1').keyup(function(){
    jQuery(".single-memberpressproduct.postid-1945 .mepr-submit").attr("disabled", !youtubeRegex.test(this.value));
});
</script>
```

Comment: `youtubeRegex ` ??? Weird name for a test for edu

Comment: Also `this.value.includes("edu")`